# Remote shut down .

Tags: windows-7

When execution of the Shutdown - m \pc name command in the control panel is done,  it creates a event log on the windows pc of the Shutdown.  Is there a way around the event log showing who remotely executed the command?

Comment: So basically you're not wanting to leave a trail behind when a computer is shutdown remotely?  What's the goal for it?

Comment: Honestly curiosity to know if it can be done.

Comment: Appropriate username is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`wevtutil cl` can clear a specific event log. To use it on a remote system, you'd need to employ something like PsExec. You'd also have to clear the log in the small time window between the `shutdown` command being issued and the system actually shutting down.

However, the act of clearing an event log generates a new event in the System log. That event says which log was cleared and who did it. Of course, the user will likely show up as `SYSTEM` if you're using PsExec, but the event will definitely raise the eyebrows of anybody who's watching. If it happens multiple times, I'm sure the target machine's owner will set up some form of auditing to catch you.

I can't imagine any good reason to do this, especially considering that you'll also obliterate possibly-important logs in the process. Don't do anything you'll regret.